# Why does .data() and .attr() return undefined although the data attribute name matches?

Tags: jquery

On clicking a div I want to pass a variable in the data attribute to the JS file.

I've tried `$(this).data('event')` and `$(this).attr('data-event')` but both return undefined.

```
<div id="event{$event['id']}" data-event="{$event['id']}">
<span>{$event['name']}</span>
</div>
```

```
$('[id^="event"]').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data('event'));
    console.log($(this).attr('data-event'));
});
```

```
//browser output
<div class="m-widget4 event-click" id="event2" data-event="2">
 <div class="m-widget4__item">
  <div class="m-widget4__ext">
   <span class="m-widget4__icon m--font-brand m--font-bold">
   Event:
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="m-widget4__info">
    <button class="m-widget4__text event-click-text">
    Olelele OKsadno saodi.
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: Developer tools screenshot as requested by Raj.]

I was expecting a string in log but got undefined every time.

Comment: Just to verify have you checked that `data-event` is not empty in the HTML? Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, the data-event is not empty from what I can see in developer tools and no errors pop up in the console.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so it's really hard to debug the problem for you without being able to see the problem

Comment: I see, sorry about that...is there any useful info I could provide?

Comment: @WisdomSeeker Please, replace your serverside html code by browsers output.

Comment: @reporter I'm sorry, I do not understand. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Execute your application in browser. After that open the sourcecode view from browser and paste the showing relevant html code into your question here.

Comment: there is a good chance that `{$event['id']}` is empty.

Comment: JQuery code is correct, just make sure JQuery code runs after your HTML code.

Comment: @WisdomSeeker please upload developer tool screenshot

Comment: @reporter  I've added, I assume, requested information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$('[data-event]').click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data('event'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-widget4 event-click" id="event2" data-event="2">
 <div class="m-widget4__item">
  <div class="m-widget4__ext">
   <span class="m-widget4__icon m--font-brand m--font-bold">
   Event:
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="m-widget4__info">
    <button class="m-widget4__text event-click-text">
    Olelele OKsadno saodi.
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Works fine :) It also works with `[id^="event"]`, i just found it to be more convenient this way.

Edit: The only thing i can imagine going wrong here is that you might have another element that has an id starting with "event", which gets selected as the parent. It would probably not have any data-event attribute and thus display undefined. You probably want your selector to be as specific as possible to rule that out.

Comment: I had a portlet `id` beginning with `event` :)! How embarrasing, haha.

Comment: It's easy for something like that to have it flow over your head. Glad that you got it solved! For the future, remember to try and not use generic selectors, unless theres no way around it. They may seem handy in the short run, but can cause some serious damage in the long run because of how not-future-proof they are. If you run into issues, simply check the output of your selector query and see if everything is correct :)